# Selector for different ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, selector

Inside an extension for `UIButton`, I create a button and add its target.

```
extension UIButton {
    convenience init(target: AnyObject) {
        self.init(type: .system)
        self.addTarget(target, action: Selector("setLang:"), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

In `ViewController`, when using the custom init function to create the   button, as target, I pass `self`.
This worked fine before upgrading my code to Swift 3. Now, however, I receive an error when tapping the button saying:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.ViewController setLang:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxx

Inside `ViewController` there is the following function declared that is supposed to be called:

```
func setLang(button: UIButton) {
    //...
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Instead of declaring the function like I did before, I need to do it the following way:

```
func setLang(_ button: UIButton) {
    //...
}
```

Hope this helps other peeps.

Answer (score 1):

i found that solution from apple developer Forums. This may help you.

```
selectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SingleQuestionViewController.selected(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: You apparently did not read the question carefully enough. I created an extension to generically create buttons in a convenient way. That also means, that the ViewController may, and will, not be the same. Hence, you can use neither `self` nor a special VC to call the function on.

Answer (score 0):

// try like this , i hope it will work for you.

```
 self.addTarget(target, action: NSSelectorFromString("setLang:"), for: .touchUpInside)
```